# How do I diagnose and resolve extreme GrantWaitTimes?

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2019

I am encountering an issue on my local development environment wherein certain queries from our application will sporadically time out. While these are relatively complicated queries, "normal" execution of them is typically <1s, which other developer's machines as well as proper environments produce consistently. Executing the queries directly against SQL Server, when the problem occurs, the query generally takes upwards of 60-90s.

Through articles and other Stack Overflow entries, I eventually traced the issue down to GrantWaitTime: in a query that took 72s, the execution plan indicates that I'd had a GWT of 70006ms, for example. I have not been able to find any material on what to do if GrantWaitTime reaches extreme values as seems to be the case here.

The problem does not appear to be related to estimation issues; in the above query, my desired and granted memory are both 30296kb, and LastRequestedMemory is 0, which I'm taking to mean that it's first request was all that was required. My SQL Server instance is configured with 16GB of memory, which I have freely available, and this behavior occurs even while there's no other activity going on against the system.

In requests where the query returns in the expected amount of time, the GrantWaitTime is generally 0. I haven't been able to identify an apparent pattern as to why this occurs sometimes, and I get the extreme values on others, though they do appear to occur in "waves".

Any thoughts or suggestions would be much appreciated.

Comment: Is your Server running on bare metal or VM? What is the server's memory capacity and what have you configured SQL Servers max memory as? Is the server dedicated to SQL Server?